# DatePicker not selecting for attribute onkeypress="return false"

Tags: java, javascript, html, webdriver

I have to select any date from date-picker UI.
The above mentioned scenario while automating my test scripts I encountered twice, for the first testcase I was successfully able to select the date from the date-picker whereas in the  second testcase I was unable to select the date from the date-picker.

The html for date-picker field in first testcase is as below

```
input id="start-date" class="dateClass" type="text" name="startDate"
```

Whereas for second testcase the HTML is

```
 input id="from-date" class="dateClass" type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return false" required="" name="fromDate"
```

I think because of the onkeypress attribute, my second test script is unable to select the date-picker.

Is there any possible way to change the onkeypress to return true in my script and select the date-picker as I did in my first test script. I am using Selenium WebDriver to automate my scripts.

Please suggest some way to select the date automatically and post the selected value into the date field.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "date-picker" in HTML (at least until HTML5's `<input type="date"/>`).  Instead, there are many different implementations that simulate some sort of calendar widget using some collection of HTML and/or JavaScript.  Each of these implementations is different and needs to be handled differently in WebDriver.  The snippets of HTML you've shown suggest you have one of the many JavaScript versions, but not which one.